# How do I add a rectangle with these characteristics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to add a rectangle to my graph: its sides should be parallel to the axes $x_{or}$ and $y_{or}$. I know how add a rectangle but I don't know how to set its sides parallel to the axes. Here is what I did so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%principal axes
      \draw[->,very thick](0,0,0)--(6,0,0);
      \draw[-] (6.2,0,0) node {\LARGE y};
      \draw[->,very thick](0,0,0)--(0,8,0);
      \draw[-] (0,8.2,0) node {\LARGE z};
      \draw[->,very thick](0,0,0)--(0,0,10);
      \draw[-] (0,0,10.5) node {\LARGE x};
%orbital plane axes
      \draw[->,very thick,red](0,0,0)--(4,-5,-1);
      \draw[-] (4,-5.5,-1.5) node {\LARGE $x_{or}$};
      \draw[->,very thick,red](0,0,0)--(0.001,7,-2);
      \draw[-] (0.001,7.2,-2.3) node {\LARGE $\vec{\ell}$};
      \draw[->,very thick,red](0,0,0)--(-5,-3,-3);
      \draw[-] (-5,-3,-2.3) node{\LARGE $y_{or}$};
%axis n
      \draw[->,very thick,blue](0,0,0)--(5,-4,-2);
      \draw[-] (5,-4.4,-2.7) node {\LARGE $\vec{n}$};
%phi angle
      \filldraw[-](0,0,0)--(10mm,-10mm) arc (0:30:10mm) --cycle;
      \draw[-] (1,-2,-1.7)node {\LARGE $\phi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following helps. An easy way to mark the various kinds of angles is to use the `angles` Ti*k*Z library. Right angles are not too difficult to do manually, as shown below. Other ones can also be done manually using computations based on `atan2`, but the `angles` Ti*k*Z library makes this task much easier.

You should probably use `\coordinate` a lot more to make your code more readable and maintainable, and also read about the `positioning` library in the [TikZ & PGF manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (there is an example below that places the node containing `$\vec{\ell}$`).

Remark:

```latex
\node[xshift=1.5pt, above=2pt of l] {$\vec{\ell}$};
```

can also be written as

```latex
\node[above right=2pt and 1.5pt of l, anchor=south] {$\vec{\ell}$};
```

Explanation: `above right` sets `anchor=south west`, but we override it with `anchor=south` because that is more convenient here.

Also, don't forget to use `$x$` instead of simply `x` in a node, when *x* represents a mathematical object. The fonts used for both cases are rather different.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
% 'calc': for the right angle marked using a “manual way”
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\LARGE, arrow/.style={->, very thick}]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

  \draw[arrow](0,0,0)--(6,0,0);
  \node at (6.2,0,0) {$y$};
  \draw[arrow](0,0,0)--(0,8,0);
  \node at (0,8.2,0) {$z$};
  \draw[arrow](0,0,0)--(0,0,10);
  \node at (0,0,10.5) {$x$};

  \coordinate (x) at (4,-5,-1);
  \node at (4,-5.5,-1.5) {$x_{or}$};
  \coordinate (y) at (-5,-3,-3);
  \node at (-5,-3,-2.3) {$y_{or}$};

  \coordinate (n) at (5,-4,-2);
  \node at (5,-4.4,-2.7) {$\vec{n}$};
  \coordinate (l) at (0.001,7,-2);
  \node[xshift=1.5pt, above=2pt of l] {$\vec{\ell}$};

  % Non-right angle using the 'angles' TikZ library
  \pic["$\phi$", fill=black!30, angle radius=1.4cm, angle eccentricity=1.2]
    {angle=x--O--n};

  \draw[arrow, blue] (0,0,0) -- (n);
  \draw[arrow, red]  (0,0,0) -- (x);
  \draw[arrow, red]  (0,0,0) -- (l);
  \draw[arrow, red]  (0,0,0) -- (y);

  % Right angle using the 'calc' TikZ library
  \coordinate (a) at ($(O)!10pt!(x)$);
  \coordinate (b) at ($(O)!10pt!(y)$);
  \draw[blue!40] (a) -- ([shift=(a)]b) -- (b);

  % Right angle using the 'angles' TikZ library (easier)
  \pic[draw=green!50!blue, angle radius=10pt] {right angle=y--O--l};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]